# Append to fields with condition

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

Input:

```
1,2,20,11
1,1,2018,111
```

Output:

```
1,02,20,11
1,01,18,111
```

i would like to insert `0` to field number 2 which is month in case if it's single number.

And want to remove first 2 digits from field number 3 which is year in case if it's 4 numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using  `awk`:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '                { $2 = sprintf("%02d", $2)   }
                  length($3) == 4 { sub("^[0-9][0-9]", "", $3) } 1' file
```

This unconditionally reformats the second comma-delimited field into a zero-filled two-digit integer.  If the third field is four characters long, its first two digits are removed.  The resulting record is then printed.

Comment: Invalid for `echo '11,1,22,4626' | sed -E -e 's/,([0-9]),/,0\1,/' -e 's/[0-9]{2}([0-9]{2})$/\1/'`

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη Where did you get that last (fourth) column from? That was not in the question.

Comment: Sorry, meant to say that field number 2 is for month and number 3 is for years. which is stable.

Answer (score 1):

using `awk`:

```
awk -F, '{ printf("%d,%02d,%d\n" ,$1, $2, substr($3, length($3)-1) ) }' infile
```

- `length($3)` returns the length of the column3; `-1` is used to let `substr($3, START[, LEN])` return length of *LEN* characters start from second last digit position as *START* (which is `length($3)-1` now). if the optional *LEN* is omitted the rest of *START* is used.

---

**EDiT** for the revised question (*now 4 columns*):

```
awk -F, '{
    printf("%d,%02d,%d%s\n" ,$1, $2, substr($3, length($3)-1), ($4?","$4:"") )
}' OFS= infile
```

for general case where N number of columns (*at least 3*):

```
awk -F, '{
     printf("%d,%02d,%d" ,$1, $2, substr($3, length($3)-1) ) }
{ $1=$2=$3=""; printf ("%s\n", (NF>3?","$0:"") ) }' OFS= infile
```

Comment: Invalid for `echo '11,1,22,4626' | awk -F, '{ printf("%d,%02d,%d\n" ,$1, $2, substr($3, length($3)-1) ) }'`

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
input file

1,2,20,11
1,1,2018,111
```

command

```
awk -F ',' '{if(length($2)==1)$2="0"$2;print $0}' inputfile | awk '{if(length($3)==4)$3=substr($3,3,2);print $0}'| sed 's/ /,/g'
```

output

```
1,02,20,11
1,01,18,111
```

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks for observation editing the answer now

Comment: Done with corrections

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this scenario is as shown:

**command**

```
perl -pe 's|^\d+,\K(\d)?(\d),(\d\d)(\d\d)?(?=,)|($1//0)."$2,".($4//$3)|e' input.txt
```

**Output**

```
1,02,20,11
1,01,18,111
```

**Explanation:**

> s|
>        ^\d+,\K             (?# keep the first comma separated field to your left)
>
> (?# $1   $2) 
>   (\d)?(\d),         (?# maybe a number followed by a definite number)
>
> (?#  $3    $4)
>   (\d\d)(\d\d)?      (?# two numbers followed maybe by two more)
>
> (?=,)              (?# we should see a comma to our right)
>
> |($1//0)."$2,".($4//$3)|e
>
> ($1 // 0) means use 0 in case $1 is undefined, IOW, field two is single digit.
>   ($4 // $3) means use $3 in case $4 is undefined, IOW, pick either of the doublets depending on the number of digits.

The /e flag in the s/// command will treat the RHS as a Perl code and shall evaluate it with whatever paramters provided and place the result of this evaluation as the RHS of the s/// command.